# JSON not showing responnse

Tags: php, json

The following code will not work for me.

```
<?php
$json_string =    file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/7ec5f6510a4656df/geolookup/forecast/q/40121    .json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$temp = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'date'};
echo "Current date is ${temp}\n";


?>
```

It works when i put it like so:

```
$temp = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
```

what am i missing here lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
$temp = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'date'};
```

For a better way of viewing JSON objects, look at [this site](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).

Comment: How about `$parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast->date;`

Comment: what about grabbing the title and fcttext? i did what you showed to grab those and also tried $title = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}->{'title'};

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm unfamiliar with php json syntax, so that could potentially be right as well. David, you just have to call the objects in the order that they're nested.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It look like you have extraneous spaces in your URL `40121    .json"`</strike> Actually spaces at the end seem to be ignored

[With spaces](http://api.wunderground.com/api/7ec5f6510a4656df/geolookup/forecast/q/40121%20%20%20%20.json)

[No spaces](http://api.wunderground.com/api/7ec5f6510a4656df/geolookup/forecast/q/4012.json)

Comment: It's actually a valid address. I went to it.